# How to store a dictionary having values as a list in redis python

Tags: python, redis

I am new to redis, I wish I had known it earlier.

I would like to store something like this in redis. It should be stored as a hash.

```
{'fruits':['apple','mango','banana'],
 'veggies':['spinach','onion','beans']}
```

I tried doing this with `redis-collection` python package. The problem I faced was, after I save the `.rdb` and reload it again I can't seem to access the keys.

In documentation, it says I should retrieve the keys its hash value. I think there has to be a better way.

Pleaase help.

Answer (score 5):

If you can consider to use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) library:

```
import redis
import json

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

Store as json:

```
data = {'fruits':['apple','mango','banana'], 'veggies':['spinach','onion','beans']}
r.set('data', json.dumps(data))
```

Fetch and convert back to dict:

```
data_fetch = json.loads(r.get('data'))

print(data_fetch.__class__) #=> <class 'dict'>
print(data_fetch) #=> {'fruits': ['apple', 'mango', 'banana'], 'veggies': ['spinach', 'onion', 'beans']}
```

Comment: thanks, but this approach is not hashing right? I am trying to use https://redis-collections.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/redis_collections/syncable.html#SyncableDefaultDict but it doesn't sync in the database. so what I want to do, load these dictionaries as hash map in redis db on my machine, then move the .rdb database to another machine and load it there

Comment: How would you update the value of a particular key in the dictionary in this case? For e.g. I want to update fruits to `['apple', 'peach', 'mango']`